# Setting up the Jasper Project Voice

Tags: software-installation, voice-recognition

I'm wondering if anyone has had any success setting up [Jasper Project](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/) on Ubuntu? in the [FAQ I found this page](https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/issues/20) but I couldn't get it to run. I was wondering if anyone who has the Jasper Project working on Ubuntu could write a Tutorial for it? Or maybe post some alternatives to Jasper.

Comment: I have, but it crashes so often as to be unusable.